# how to show a progress bar on file's icon

Tags: macos, cocoa, progress-bar

You know there is a mini progress bar on the file's icon when we copy a file or download file with safari and chrome.

I am wondering how to let it shown in Finder window when I'm copying or download files with my own code.

Could somebody help me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got the way by query file/directory attributes myself. It's quit simple.

Get attributes of the file you want to show a progress bar on it's icon

```
NSDictionary *fileAttr = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
```

Get extend attributes

```
NSDictionary *extendAttr = [fileAttr objectForKey:@"NSFileExtendedAttributes"];
```

Create a Mutable copy of extendAttr and change some value in it

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableExtendAttr = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:extendAttr];
// create data of progress value
NSData *progressData = [@"0.1" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
// change it
[mutableExtendAttr setObject:progressData forKey:@"com.apple.progress.fractionCompleted"];
```

Create a mutable copy of fileAttr

```
 NSMutableDictionary *mutableFileAttr = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:fileAttr];
 // change extend attr
 [mutableFileAttr setObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:mutableExtendAttr] forKey:extendAttrKey];
 // change file/dir create date to the special one
 // if not , progress bar will not show
 [mutableFileAttr setObject:[NSDate dateWithString:@"1984-01-24 08:00:00 +0000"] forKey:NSFileCreationDate];
 // set attribute to file
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:mutableFileAttr ofItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
```

Now you'll find it the progress bar showed up.

Comment: update:It seems that chrome's download file name ended with .crdownload didnt use this method, I was wondering that how chrome make it.

Comment: @UJey I have only tested OSX 10.8 'cause I only have a 10.8 Mac mini.

Comment: But issue [139027](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=139027) suggests that Chrome uses the same method.

Comment: Is there a way to have progress bar added to launchpad icons in the similar way?

Comment: @DavidKocher [Chromium issue #10827207](https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/10827207/#ps5040) rather suggest they are relying on [NSProgress](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/progress) introduced with mountain lion support.
I was not able to make the file attribute method work on macOS Sierra.

Comment: After I put up the progress bar how do I remove it?

Comment: @Lucasware, make a mutable copy the file attribute, remove the NSFileCreationDate entry, set it back to the file.

Comment: Thanks but can you give me an example, I tried but it didn't work properly

Comment: @Lucasware, sorry I write the wrong key name, please remove @"NSFileExtendedAttributes" entry

Comment: You might need to set the date to 1904-01-01:00:00:00+0000 to make it work on 10.11+

Comment: Actually it looks like an [NSProgress publish] method is used by Chrome to report progress on a file
https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/10827207/patch/6001/7005

Answer (score 0):

One starting point would be to use a `NSProgressIndicator`, then `[progressIndicator setIndeterminate:NO];`. Your updates/background operation should then **not** block the main thread. `NSProgressIndicator` is a bit different for an AppKit widget -- it permits *some* updates from secondary threads. Of course, updates to the 'current progress' may also be enqueued upon the main thread's run loop.

Comment: I dont think you've get what I described above. example, when you copy a big file(such as a 1GB file) to new directory, it will not complete immediately, then look at the new file in directory, there is something like progress bar under its icon. what I'm interested is how to show the progress bar(under the file's icon) when I'm writing a file with my code.

Comment: FYI: you could find some info in my answer, if you insterested @justin